# trying to get an md5 from badly named files

Tags: freebsd, truenas

I am trying to get the md5 from a lot of files. I would use ls to list files and md5 to get a hash of all the files from multiple directories like so

`` md5 `ls -R /` ``

this would work if the names of the files didn't include spaces like this

`[AkihitoSubs] Zetsuen no Tempest - 21 [BD 1920x1080 x256 10Bit AC3].mkv`

how would one get an md5 hash from all these poorly named files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find ./ -name "*" -exec md5sum {} \;
```

Should do the trick.